# Is the date format of the native mobile datepicker dependant on the date format of the device

Tags: android, mobile, livecode

I am trying to use a datepicker in an app and the device uses the d/m/yy date format. I am getting the wrong date on the date picker. What is the work around so that the date will be right irrespective of the device's date format.

Everything I have read suggest that the datepicker uses the format that the user has selected for the device.

I have a data entry field in livecode which has the following code:

```
on openField

   if environment() is "mobile" then

      mobilePickDate "date",field "field"

   end if

end openField
```

The value of field "field" is 1/3/15 and in choose date format on my device I have chosen 31/12/2015. This means that the datepicker should defualt to 1 March 2015, instead I get 3 January 2015.

**Additional Info**

I tried the following code:-

```
on openField

   set the usesystemdate to true

   if environment() is "mobile" then

      put field "field" into tdate
      convert tdate to dateitems
      answer tdate
      mobilePickDate "date",field "field"

   else

      put field "field" into tdate
      convert tdate to dateitems
      answer tdate

   end if

end openField
```

The message box text is different on desktop and mobile with the same date-time setting. Desktop returned 2015,3,1,0,0,0,1 mobile returned 2015,1,3,0,0,0,7.

Desktop correct mobile wrong. So I am wondering if android uses American date irrespective of the system setting as is the case with visual basic.

Answer (score 0):

Base on the tests that I have dine and response on this link http://forums.livecode.com/viewtopic.php?f=53&t=21655 it has become apparent that changing the date format of the device does not change the format in the android programming environment. So I have developed the following workaround.

Create a function to determine the date format

```
function  GetDateFormat 

   set the usesystemdate to true
   put "1/3/15" into tdate
   convert tdate to dateitems
   set itemdel to comma

   switch item 2 of tdate

      case 1

         return "mm/dd/yy"

      case 3

         return "dd/mm/yy"


   end switch

end GetDateFormat
```

convert the date sent to the date picker to "mm/dd/yyyy" format

```
on openField

   set the usesystemdate to true
   put field "field" into tdate

   if environment() is "mobile" then

      switch GetDateFormat()

        case "mm/dd/yy"

            set itemdel to "/"

            put item 2 of tdate & "/" & item 1 of tdate & "/" & item 3 of tdate into tdate

      end switch

      convert tdate to dateitems
      mobilePickDate "date",tdate

   end if

end openField
```

Answer (score -1):

Try setting the useSystemDate property to true at the top of your handler. That will allow LiveCode to interpret the results of the date picker according to the user's system date settings.

Comment: I have tried that with no luck. The value displayed by the date picker after `mobilePickDate "date",field "field"` remains the same irrespective of the useSystemDate property. I note that on desktop environment using `put field "field" into tdate
      convert tdate to dateitems
      answer tdate` gives different result based on the useSystemDate property